# Android -How to populate a query according to the user click item of GridView?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my grid view there are 9 items. When user clicks an item I want to send user to another activity with a list view. But List view items are populated from a SQLite DB and it depends on the item which user clicks.

Ex: If user click the 1st item on the grid view , list view should populate with according to the 1st item .

As an example query should be like following code.

```
SELECT organization_name from TABLE_NAME where CATEGORY_ID=ItemIdOfGridView
```

Where do I put this query in onItemClick of GridView ?

Comment: just pass an id of the clicked item in the Intent's extras and read the data in the second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gridview's `setOnItemClickListener` to get position.

```
 gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                  Intent intet=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,second.class);
                 intent.putExtra("id", id);
                  startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Then in second class get the extra and do as you need.

**edit:**

The position specify the clicked item position of grid view.Then you can get your necessary data from the list or arraylist of gridview which is used for populating gridview using this position.
i.e.

```
data=yourList.get(position).getData();
```

Comment: and what would you pass the position for? how can "position" be useful for reading the data in the second activity? downvote then

Comment: position is useless,  how can you get adapter's data in the second activity?  you have to pass "id", not "position"

Comment: I will get data at first class from list and then pass to second as extra

Comment: no, just pass "id" (see `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick` documentation), and read whatever you want in the target activity